# How to get the transaction history from paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I dont know how to get transaction history in paypal.I have go through the rest api for the paypal.
And found following api to fetch transaction history.

```
  https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/id
```

I dont know what could be sales id here.And do i just need to enter the url in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you HAVE to use the REST API?  I personally prefer the classic API's at this point because their REST API just doesn't have all the same features yet.

For your case, the classic API includes [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) and [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) which can help you pull history and details about specific transactions.

Comment: Does anyone know if it is still the case that the REST API doesn't support TransactionSearch yet?  I haven't found it anywhere, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: It appears the Classic API is still the way to go as of Feb. 6 2018.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#can-i-retrieve-the-history-of-transactions-created-with-the-nvpsoap-apis-using-the-rest-api